# Dropping NAS from columns and rows at the same time

Tags: r, na, r-caret

Working with R, I've been doing some correlation matrix by `pairwise.complete.obs` for my data and I had some variables with `NA`'s alongs them, which doesn't let me do a `findCorrelation` from `caret` to drop variables.

I do not wish to use `na.omit` on my dataset, since it does have quite few `NA`'s and changes or nullifies my pairwise correlation; but omitting my `NA`'s in the matrix just removes rows, and I need to remove the columns as well to end up with a NxN matrix.

Is there a function that allows this? So far I cant manage to find one, and maybe I should just do a custom function to retrieve the index of columns with `NA`'s and do a `df[-q,-q]` to eliminate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
q <- complete.cases(my_matrix)
my_matrix[q,q]
```